# Forcing MFA on accounts in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting the following on behalf of a Snowflake User)

---

I'm looking to find a way to force MFA on all accounts, but understand that this can only be accomplished on a user-by-user basis. Is there any way to set it so that all users must use MFA?

Can anyone recommend a script that does this for all users?

---

Any recommendations (or alternatives) would be greatly appreciated!  THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mandatory opt-in for MFA as of now but a feature request for central MFA administration is in process. To identify those users who have not enrolled, one can use login_history/login_history_by_user information schema views to highlight those users. Specifically, when the column 'SECOND_AUTHENTICATION_FACTOR' is NULL, we know users have not enrolled in MFA.

Reference:
[login_history](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/login_history.html#login-history-login-history-by-user)

Answer (score 0):

There is the option `MINS_TO_BYPASS_MFA` that gives people time to login, and enable MFA themselves, and if they don't they are locked out.. so you tell them, log in and set it up...

[MFA docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-mfa.html)